# pan gesture recognise button issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I set a pan gesture recogniser to recognise my touch on some buttons and am running into the following issue. I am trying to add an action to each of the buttons. I'm testing this by telling each different button to become highlighted when I touch them. So far when I keep my finger pressed on the screen en slide around only button1 and button2 show up (as written in the code).

But for some reason I can still see other buttons highlight the same way when I press them individually. Any idea how to solve this so that they only respond to. If button.tag == 3 etc.. Then respond? Here is the code. (This is all the code in the project and a few buttons in the interface builder.)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// Add Gesture to track the finger
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    for (UIButton *button in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            if (button.tag == 1) {
                button.highlighted = CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, point);

            } else if (button.tag == 2) {
                button.highlighted = CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, point);
            } //
        }
    }
}
else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    for (UIButton *button in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            button.highlighted = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

}

EDIT :

```
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanned:)];
- (void)handlePanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)thePanner{

if (thePanner.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ){
   //disable button 
}else if (thePanner.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //enable button
}else if ( thePanner.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ){
 //enable button
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `panGestureRecognizer`, but you aren't checking to see if where you touched is where a button is currently located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't checking to see if where you are touching is where a button is located.

Quickest solution I see is:

Create properties for each of your buttons, we'll call them `button1`, `button2` and `button3`.

Create your `panGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}
```

Your method to handle the pan:

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //create a CGpoint so you know where you are touching  
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    //just to show you where you are touching...
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));

    //check your button frame's individually to see if you are touching inside it
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button1.frame, touchPoint))
    {
        NSLog(@"you're panning button1");
    }
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.button2.frame, touchPoint))
    {
        NSLog(@"you're panning button2");
    }
    else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button3.frame, touchPoint))
    {
        NSLog(@"you're panning button3");
    }
```

And that should be it.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked ! There are 2 other things I am encountering now. 1 : When I slightly move my finger within 1 button, I can keep on hearing the same sound being played over and over again very rapidly. I'm assuming every time I move my finger slightly within the button it keeps detecting my touch over and over again. How can I prevent this from happening and only have an action happen once I hit the button the first time? And 2nd. It's only detecting my slides from to other buttons now, it is not detecting my touch down at all. Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Btw, I added a sound file to be triggered and replaced that by the NSLog announcement. Just so we're clear.

Comment: @MilesH. you're correct in your assumption regarding the sound playing repeatedly, it detect your touch as soon as it moves to another position. I would check to see if I'm already panning the button before I play the sound, that way it only happens once. Re: detecting touch downs, it detects them for me. Make sure they are still enabled (in IB or elsewhere) and that they will highlight when touched. If you are still bugged, post another question to handle the sound trigger.

Comment: Ok, thanks @CaptJak. I appreciate the input ! Detecting touch downs makes sense to me, I disabled that while testing the current code. Problem solved. I created a new question about how to see if I'm already panning the button before I play the sound. How would you go about that?

Comment: I edit my initial post and I found this new code that I found. The problem with this code is, it will enabled or disable my button, but the sound is not coming from the button, it is coming from the pan gesture and the location of the button. I'm guessing it's in that direction though correct?

Comment: @MilesH. I am not sure what you want to do with the new code you found. You could have IBActions for the buttons as well so that pressing them will also make the sound. You don't have to enable and disable them continuously.

Comment: That's correct. I do have IBActions, for the touch down. I just thought within first glance this could solve the problem, but it's not the buttons I need to disable it's the the fact if I'm already panning or not. How would you go about that?

Comment: Let's move over to your new question @MilesH. Once I have a good answer, I'll let you know (don't know when I'll be able to though).

Comment: Ok, thank you ! I appreciate the help so much ! I have been dealing with this problem for a week now and this is the closest I've gotten so far. So again I appreciate all the help and advice you have given. This is the link to the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351206/pan-gesture-issue-slight-movement-within-uibutton-detection