# pan gesture issue, slight movement within UIButton detection

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So I created this pan gesture recogniser to detect my touch on several UIBUttons. The idea is. I am looking for having the ability to slide my finger over all the buttons and trigger each and single one of them while I touch them. Right now I am able to slide over all the buttons and trigger the sound with this code. There is one problem that is occurring and that is when I replace the sound file with the NSLog statement, Every tiny little move I make with my finger within the same button keeps on repeating sound over and over again really fast. It reacts to the slightest movement.

How can I enable only hearing the sound one time after my finger touches the button and have the ability to play the same sound again when my finger touches the same button again. Pretty much the effect you get when you touch or slide your finger over a real piano.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}




//Method to handle the pan:



-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
//create a CGpoint so you know where you are touching  
CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

//just to show you where you are touching...
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));

//check your button frame's individually to see if you are touching inside it
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button1.frame, touchPoint))
{
    NSLog(@"you're panning button1");
}
else if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.button2.frame, touchPoint))
{
    NSLog(@"you're panning button2");
}
else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button3.frame, touchPoint))
{
    NSLog(@"you're panning button3");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an NSMutableArray for detecting which sounds have been played since the last touch down event (pseudo code follows, please replace with proper method names and signatures):

```
NSMutableArray *myPlayedSounds;
void touchDown:(UITouch *) touch
{
    //Empty played sounds list as soon as a touch event is sensed
    [myPlayedSounds removeAllObjects];
}

-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
//create a CGpoint so you know where you are touching  
CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

//just to show you where you are touching...
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));

//check your button frame's individually to see if you are touching inside it
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button1.frame, touchPoint) && [myPlayedSounds containsObject:@"button1"] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"you're panning button1");
    [myPlayedSounds addObject:@"button1"];
}
else if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.button2.frame, touchPoint) && [myPlayedSounds containsObject:@"button2"] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"you're panning button2");
    [myPlayedSounds addObject:@"button2"];

}
else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button3.frame, touchPoint) && [myPlayedSounds containsObject:@"button3"] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"you're panning button3");
    [myPlayedSounds addObject:@"button3"];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks ABHashmi ! This is starting to make sense! The array is still confusing to me at this point as in, are you referring to the actual button1,2,3 or are you calling the 'sound file' underneath the button called 'button1,2,3' that is suppose to be in the project (my sounds are called differently, just want to be clear I understand) etc? Because button1, 2, 3 are just IBOutlets at this point and there are no IBActions with sounds in them, just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: @MilesH. it might help to go through this [tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray)

Comment: Miles, the array is just to keep track of which sounds have been played. It could be any string or NSNumber value you choose for each button. I mean, I could add string @"yo" if button1 is pressed, but that also implies that I will be checking for whether @"yo" exists in my array or not.

Simply put:

a) value exists:==> sound has been played. b) value does not exist:==> sound has not been played yet. Also, whenever I choose to play a sound, I add its corresponding value to the array, effectively marking the sound as played.

Comment: Hm, ok. So after this code NSMutableArray *myPlayedSounds; I just add whatever sounds I want to get triggered in square brackets and replace the button 1, 2 etc names you mentioned in the code by whatever name my sound files have, correct? And thank you for the tutorial CaptJak, reading through it atm. I'm also not good at reading Objective-C at all and since I'm doing my project in Swift I'm trying to translate it at the same time to see how it would work in swift. :)

Comment: myPlayedSounds always holds the names/values/whatever that indicates which sounds have **already** been played since the user last put his finger on the screen. As you go sliding through and, say, hit button1, let's assume you played "sound1" and added string @"sound1played" to the array. Then you go forward, slide back and hit button1 again. But this time, when you check if @"sound1played" exists in myPlayedSounds, it tells you the string exists, meaning the "sound1" has been played, so don't play it again.

Comment: @MilesH., here is the [swift equivalent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105). I would suggest going through both since the Rys tutorial gives a better overall concept.